# Gradle: Output files of different JavaCompile tasks

Tags: java, gradle, build, compilation

I have a gradle build script with different `JavaCompile` tasks. They compile the sources with different compiler arguments. How can I add `Jar` tasks for all of these different `JavaCompile` tasks. The tasks store the generated classfiles in different directories.

This is the build file I'm using:
https://github.com/gsaga/asm_signature_checker/blob/ASM_6_1_1_signature_checker/build.gradle

Comment: Add your build file to the question.

Comment: @soufrk build file added to the post.